# javascript mongoose conflicting variables in arrayfilter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    contact             :[{//1st level
        phone           : String,
        address2            : String,
        city                : String,
        state               : String,
        dept_id         :{
            type                    : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref                     : 'dept'
        }
    }],
    employment_detail   :[{
        employment_date     : Date,
        employment_type     : String,
        dept_id         :{
            type                    : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref                     : 'dept'
        },
    }],
    positions_held      :[{
        post                : String,
        appointment_date    : String,
        dept_id         :{
            type                    : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref                     : 'dept'
        },
    }]
})
```

When I want to update contact array using the arrayFilter and dept_id and at the same time update 
employment_detail using dept_id it does not allow me to update those arrays apparently because positions_held
the last array also has dept_id and I cannot do away with dept_id because there are times I would need an array's
 object item. This is a shortened script

```
UserModel.updateOne({
        _id:userid
    }, 
    {$set:{'contact.$[first].state':'California',
          'employment_detail.$[second].employment_date':Date.now}},
    {arrayFilters:[{'first.dept_id': thisidthedeptid},
                   {'second.dept_id': thisidthedeptid},]} .......
```

How can go about it, how can I go about it.